# How to properly build package from sources

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile, gstreamer, automake

I'm using `ubuntu 18.04`.

I want to modify and build a project and install it as a package. For example `gstreamer1.5`.

So I clone repo, modify code and use `./autogen.sh` and `make install` in project folder. Why don't I see it in `apt list` then? Also there is no files in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.5/`.

The reason why I want it to behave as the original package is becase I want to build another project that uses it (kurento media server). So I just want to remove some plugins I don't need that use another packages as deps I cannot use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apt list` is from the Linux distribution. You custom made things won't appear there magically.

If you `make install` from your custom tree your libraries and plugins will land in `/usr/local/lib/..` (note the `local` path). You may have some control over it by setting the `prefix` path. Just be careful you don't break you system by overwriting with broken libraries.

Comment: Thank you for answer. So can I just put new .so files in the same folder as original ones in order to make it work?

Comment: Not recommended.. you system requires newer versions of these libraries. If you downgrade other things are likely to fail.